# how to hide one div when another div is active in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have two div login and forget password. i want on forget password login block should be hide and when login block needed forget block should be hidden. Now i able to handle forgot password block , but login block i am not able to handle. I want login block hide on click of forgot button. I have written my own code below. Can some one please suggest me how can i do that.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './loginForm.css';


const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [forgotPass, setForgotPass] = useState(false);

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to={routePaths.DASHBOARD} push />;
    }
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Header className="header">
                <div>
                    <img src={logo} className="logo" />
                    <span className="lft">
                        <a href="#" className="contact"><MessageOutlined /></a>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </Header>
            <Content className="content-screen">
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={8} />
                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={8}>
                        <div id="loginDiv" className="screen">
                            <Card title="Login to Relocatte" headStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#69c0ff', border: 1 }}>
                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                    {/* <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Login</h2> */}
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                                            <Input size="large" placeholder="Enter User Email Here..." onChange={(e) => setValue('email', e.target.value)} />
                                            <ErrorTag errors={errors} name="email" />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                                            <Input type="password" size="large" placeholder="Enter User Password Here..." onChange={(e) => setValue('encryptedPassword', e.target.value)} />
                                            <ErrorTag errors={errors} name="encryptedPassword" />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col span={7} style={{ padding: 15 }} className="forget">
                                            <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col span={7} style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                                            <Input style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} type="submit" value="Login" className="login-form-button" shape="round" icon="rollback" />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col span={10} style={{ padding: 15 }} className="forget">
                                            <a href="#" onClick={() => setForgotPass(!forgotPass)}>Forgot Password</a>
                                            {/* <button onClick={() => setForgotPass(!forgotPass)}>Forgot Password</button> */}
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </form>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={8}>
                        {/* forgot div goes here */}
                        {forgotPass
                        && (
                            <div className="screen">
                                <Card title="Forgot Password" headStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#69c0ff', border: 1 }}>
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                        {/* <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Login</h2> */}
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                                                <Input size="large" placeholder="Enter Registered Email Here..." onChange={(e) => setValue('', e.target.value)} />
                                                <ErrorTag errors={errors} name="" />
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col span={12} style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                                                <Input style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} type="submit" value="Send Reset Link" className="login-form-button" shape="round" icon="rollback" />
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col span={10} style={{ padding: 15 , textAlign: "right"}} className="forget">
                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => setForgotPass(!forgotPass)}>Login</a>
                                                {/* <button onClick={() => setForgotPass(!forgotPass)}>Forgot Password</button> */}
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </form>
                                </Card>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Content>
            <Footer className="footer-back">
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} className="foot-child-1">
                        All Right Reserved© 2020 Relocatte
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} className="foot-child-2">
                        <span><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></span>
                        <span> | </span>
                        <span><a href="#">Term & Conditions</a></span>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Footer>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please check this example:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [forgotPass, setForgotPass] = useState(false);

    function handleLogin(event) {

    }

    function handleForgot(event) {
        setForgotPass(!forgotPass);
    }

    function handleReset(event) {
        alert('Your password is reset');
        setForgotPass(!forgotPass);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {forgotPass ?
                (<div>
                    Username: <input/> <br/>
                    <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset Password</button>
                </div>)
                :
                (<div>
                    Username: <input/> <br/>
                    Password: <input/> <br/>
                    <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
                    <button onClick={handleForgot}>Forgot Password</button>
                </div>)
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it

Using ternary operator

```
return (<div className="container">
  {forgotPass ? <div>Forget password div </div> : <div> Login Div</div>}
</div>)
```

Using CSS

```
return (<div className="container">
  <div className={forgotPass ? "show" : "hide"}>Forget password div </div>
  <div className={!forgotPass ? "show" : "hide"}> Login Div</div>}
</div>)
```

in your css:

```
.show { display: 'block' }
.hide { display: 'none' }
```